# Android, Phonegap - cannot find my apps name in suggestion list play store search box

Tags: android, cordova

Our app is not listing in the play store suggestion box, when i type the matching keyword, it returns some other apps name which matches the key.

Ex: When I type a keyword "easym" it will suggest some other apps name in the search box. but my apps is not listing there. Please find the attached screenshot. [Check the attached image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNSxK.png)

I tired in the android sony xperia(version 4), android samsung(2.3,2.2) & in google play store also [play store link](https://play.google.com/store/)

Comment: Application will take some time to get displayed in the market. One way to see whether your application is available or not is to use the link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name_given_in_androidmanifest.xml_file>

Comment: When have you uploaded the apk?

Comment: Its uploaded a month before, i can get my app in the play store by searching. But my problem is when is type some matching keyword of my app name it is not listing in the suggestion search list(autocomplete).